# SQL Query not updating the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I was getting an error from my processing form down below. I'm not sure why it isn't updating to the database when I hit submit. It says it has been successful but yet the databse has not been updated?!

I think it maybe because of the "mysqli_stmt_execute" but I'm not sure.
Any thoughts :/
Thanks.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include_once 'connection.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
    $hashedPwd = md5($pwd); 

     //Error Handling
    //Checking for empty fields  
    if(empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit();
    }else{
        //Checking if the input characters are valid
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last) ){
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
            exit();
        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Staff_ID='$uid'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($resultCheck > 0){
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                exit();
            }else{
                //Hasing the password surecirty

            }
            }
        }
    //Insert user into database

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (Firstname, Lastname, Staff_ID, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";

            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
                echo"SQL Error";
                } else{
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $first, $last, $uid, $pwd);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    }
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();

    }else{
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();

}
?>
```

Comment: Check the result of the `bind` and `execute` as well. Use the error reporting function. You should parameterize every query, not just the `insert`. Dont escape when parameterizing. Additionally don't use `md5` for hashing.

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` if you're using `bind_param`. That will cause double escaping of special characters.

Comment: @user3783243 Sorry for asking, but I am a bit of a novice at php, how would I be able to check the result of bind and execute functions. Would I use echo? Would you be able to show me an example :)

Comment: I can not see any update queries there :)

Comment: @hassan How would I be able to add an update query? :)

Comment: `var_dump` this `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $first, $last, $uid, $pwd);` and the `execute` a non TRUE means the function failed. Then use error reporting to see the reason for that functions failure.